# Can lasso be used for feature selection in a setting that generating 100 models and aggregating consensus of feature selected by good models?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, lasso-regression

I have a dataset say 500000 features(p) or predictors and 200 observations, correspondingly 200 response(categorical- 2 classes). Now, I want to get important features from 500000 total. Does it make sense to do cross-validated lasso in a loop so that each loop gets a lambda.min and fitting a model using lambda min, then selecting features(from the loop)? And finally, taking consensus of features selected by all iterations. Note: each iteration in the loop uses different training and testing data, however, the ratio of split is 70%(training) and 30%(testing) for all iterations. How valid this approach would be statistically? or any other suggestions to solve the problem?

The ultimate objective of the problem is feature selection.

```
num_run<- 100
for (r in 1:num_run) {
    message("starting iteration: ", r, " at ", Sys.time())
    set.seed(r)#for randomisation of samples
    split <- createDataPartition(Y, p = 0.7)$Resample1
    X_train <- X[split,]
    X_test <- X[-split,]
    y_train <- Y[split]
    y_test <- Y[-split]
    cv.lasso <- cv.glmnet(x = X_train, y = y_train, 
                        alpha = 1,
                        type.measure = "auc",
                        nfolds = 5,
                        parallel = TRUE,
                        trace.it = 1,
                        family="binomial")
    #get best lambda from the cross validated
    best_lambda <- cv.lasso$lambda.min
    # train best model
    lasso_best_model<- glmnet(x= X_train, y = y_train,
                                 alpha = 1, lambda = best_lambda,
                                 family = "binomial", trace.it = 1)
 
    non_zero_indices <- which(lasso_best_model$beta!=0)
    best_features[[r]] <- colnames(X)[non_zero_indices]
}
```